# How to assert timer callback in c# xunit unit test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, timer, xunit

I have a `OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup` `BackgroundService` in `.NET 8` as shown below.

`OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup`:

```cs
public class OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup(
    ILogger<OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup> logger,
    TimeProvider timeProvider,
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        timeProvider.CreateTimer(Backup, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        stoppingToken.Register(() => logger.LogWarning($"{nameof(OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup)} is stopping due to host shut down."));
    }

    private void Backup(object? state)
    {
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var offlineDatabaseBackupService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOfflineDatabaseBackupService>();
        offlineDatabaseBackupService.Backup();
    }
}
```

I have written uni test to test the behavior. Here is my `xunit` unit test,

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup_ExecuteAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    var mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService = new Mock<IOfflineDatabaseBackupService>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_ => mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Object);
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var timeProvider = new TestTimeProvider(now);
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = NullLogger<OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup>.Instance;
    var configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

    // Act
    using var offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup = new OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup(logger, timeProvider, serviceProvider);
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.StartAsync(default);
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask!; // --> Backup() should be called
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); // --> Backup() should be called

    // Assert
    offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully.Should().BeTrue();
    mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Verify(x => x.Backup(), Times.AtLeast(2));
}
```

Here is my `TestTimeProvider.cs`,

```cs
internal class TestTimeProvider(DateTimeOffset now) : TimeProvider
{
    public override DateTimeOffset GetUtcNow() => now;

    public override ITimer CreateTimer(TimerCallback callback, object? state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
    {
        return base.CreateTimer(callback, state, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }

    public void Advance(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        now = now.Add(timeSpan);
    }
}
```

When I run the test I expect `Callback` `Backup` method to be called two times. One because of `await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask!;` and another time because of `timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));` but getting the exception message as follows

> Expected invocation on the mock at least 2 times, but was 0 times: x
> => x.Backup()

Upon debugging I have noticed that before the first `Backup()` call gets executed the assertion line gets completed and throws above error.

Please can you assist me on what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the above challenge.

I came to know that there are test fakes available from `Microsoft` as `Nuget` Packages.

For `TimerProvider` - `Microsoft.Extensions.TimeProvider.Testing`

And simply changed the test as shown below with `FakeTimeProvider`

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup_ExecuteAsync()
{
    // Arrange
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    var mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService = new Mock<IOfflineDatabaseBackupService>();
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(_ => mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Object);
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    var timeProvider = new FakeTimeProvider(); // --> Changed here
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var logger = new FakeLogger<OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup>();
    var configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

    // Act
    using var offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup = new OfflineHourlyDatabaseBackup(logger, timeProvider, serviceProvider);
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.StartAsync(default);
    await offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask!;
    timeProvider.Advance(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    // Assert
    offlineHourlyDatabaseBackup.ExecuteTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully.Should().BeTrue();
    mockOfflineDatabaseBackupService.Verify(x => x.Backup(), Times.AtLeast(2));
}
```

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/fake-it-til-you-make-it-to-production/